# How do I cross-compile from Linux targeting Windows using cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, cross-compiling, clang++

I am currently attempting to cross compile targeting Windows using cmake in Linux Subsystem for Windows Ubuntu. I am compiling form Linux because I want to be able to support multiple platforms.

I am unsure how to make this work, and have no preference of compiler.

See the following code and build output for my current attempt.

`CMakeLists.txt file`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/win.toolchain.cmake)

project(environment.exe)

find_package(SDL2 REQUIRED)
include_directories(environment.exe ${SDL2_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# get executable src files
file(GLOB_RECURSE environment.exe_src ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/environment/*.cpp)

# add environment.exe executable
add_executable(environment.exe ${environment.exe_src})
target_link_libraries(environment.exe ${SDL2_LIBRARIES})

# set output dir
set_target_properties(
    environment.exe
    PROPERTIES
    # ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/suite/lib"
    # LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/suite/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin/environment"
)
```

`win.toolchain.cmake file`

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR x64)#i686

set(triple x64-pc-win32)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${triple})
```

`BASH output`

```
a@DESKTOP-DCHFQSJ:/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment$ ./build.sh
Checking for make installation.
make is installed.
Checking for cmake installation.
cmake is installed.
Checking for mingw-w64 installation.
mingw-w64 is installed.
Checking for g++-mingw-w64 installation.
g++-mingw-w64 is installed.
Checking for libsdl2-dev installation.
libsdl2-dev is installed.
./build.sh: line 30: cd: ./build: No such file or directory
Running cmake on './build'
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/clang -- broken
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_8a6e7/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
    /usr/bin/clang --target=x64-pc-win32    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj   -c "/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c"
    error: unknown target triple 'x64-pc-windows-msvc19.11.0', please use -triple or -arch
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/build.make:65: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
    make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_8a6e7.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_8a6e7/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_8a6e7/fast] Error 2




  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/mnt/e/d/User/Software Projects/windows-software-environment/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: It looks like you chose to use `clang` but not a cross compiler version of `clang`.  What is `./build.sh`.  It appears to find the cross compilers you installed but you don't use them.  You should figure out how to setup the environment first and how to invoke the compiler manually.  Then you create the toolchain file with the correct information.

Comment: `./build.sh` just checks for packages, and installs them if they are not there, then runs `cmake` followed by `make`. Tho other compilers it checks for are from a previous attempt.